# Differrence between install and import in Jupyterlab Notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

What is the difference between the `install` statement and the `import` statement in Jupyterlab Notebooks?

```
!pip install xlrd


import pandas as pd
```

Why can't we say `!pip install pandas` or `import xlrd` for example?

[Screenshot of my notebook : https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxNjA.png ]

Comment: pip is to download and install new modules not already on your pc. import ... is to use one already installed. So if import does not work: 1 use pip, then 2 use import

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `install` command is used to install a python library. In your case you have already installed `xlrd`, hence the output `Requirement already satisfied`.

The `import` command is used to import an already existing library to your code. Basically it tells python to use this library in your program.

Comment: Why you downvoted my comment. Please remove that ~~Thanks

Answer (score 0):

pip Installing means we are downloading the code that already return somewhere python expects those kinds of things to be, and the import statement says "go look there for something named pandas now, and make the data available to me for use".

Answer (score 0):

When you say `pip install <module_name>` you ask the system to install the module on your computer from available sources. When you import the module into your script with `import <module_name>` it asks python to import the library available in the computer. If the library (module) is not present in the computer, it will give you an error and ask you to install it. So `pip` is to install modules on your computer and `import` is to used to get modules present in computer to be used in scripts.
NOTE: As you are using JupyterLab there you use `!pip` install as the "!" symbols tells JupyterLab to process this a system command.